# Java regex to remove single quotes around anything

Tags: java, regex

I have a huge string that looks like:

```
widgets: '{some-really-huge-string-omitted-for-brevity}'
```

And I would like to remove the single-quotes so that I get:

```
widgets: {some-really-huge-string-omitted-for-brevity}
```

In reality, `some-really-huge-string-omitted-for-brevity` is a massive string containing alphanumeric characters, punctuation, basically everything under the sun. My best attempt so far:

```
bigString = bigString.replaceAll("widgets: '\\{*\\}'", "widgets: \\{*\\}");
```

Doesn't throw any exceptions/errors, but also doesn't change a thing! When I print `bigString`, it's still the same as before the replace! Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the quotes are always in those places. (ie. 9th and last characters of the String), then just use substring to trim and rejoin. Scanning through the entire String would be slow and pointless.

```
String trimmed = hugeString.substring(0, 9) + hugeString.substring(10, hugeString.length() - 1);
```

**Updated**

Seeing as you accepted this answer, this might be a more efficient version:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(hugeString);
b.deleteCharAt(9);
b.deleteCharAt(b.length() - 1);
String trimmed = b.toString();
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, none of the regexes worked. But this one did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "widgets: '{some-really-huge-string-omitted-for-brevity}'";
System.out.println (str.replaceAll ("'([^']*)'", "$1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string= string.replace("'", "");
```

If you want to remove all single quotes around anything try above code .

```
string= string.replace("'{", "{").replace("}'","}");
```

If you want to remove single quotes before opening curly braces "{" and closing curly braces "}".

Comment: What happens if the body of the "omitted-for-brevity" contains single quotes?

Comment: Exactly - thanks Achintya but this doesn't help me in the given situation.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Question is  remove all single quotes around anything so I suggested that answer.Thanks